# Libgdx - fade away effect

Tags: android, libgdx

Currently I have implemented my fade effect away, so that when the screen opens up it starts with `[alpha = 0]`, and then for each Sprite that it is drawing it does `[alpha += 2.5f * delta_time]` until it reaches `[alpha + 2.5f * delta >= 1]`...

And the same applies to `[if screen = closed] --> [alpha = 1]` and `[alpha -= 2.5f * delta_time]` until it reaches `[alpha - 2.5f * delta <= 0]`...

This works wonderfully on my windows, but on my phone it looks... Well sometimes it looks fine, but most of the times the phone keeps lagging a little, so it sometimes skips like the entire fade in effect. Fade out effect works fine, probably because all the objects are already created!

So is my game lagging on fade if effect because objects and the game is being created? How would you go about fixing this?

EDIT

```
public void openScreen(float delta) {
    playButton.getButton().setColor(playButton.getButton().getColor().r, playButton.getButton().getColor().g, playButton.getButton().getColor().b, alpha);
    shopButton.getButton().setColor(shopButton.getButton().getColor().r, shopButton.getButton().getColor().g, shopButton.getButton().getColor().b, alpha);
    scoreFont.setColor(scoreFont.getColor().r, scoreFont.getColor().g, scoreFont.getColor().b, alpha);

    if (alpha + (2.5f * delta) >= 1) {
        alpha = 1f;
        playButton.getButton().setColor(playButton.getButton().getColor().r, playButton.getButton().getColor().g, playButton.getButton().getColor().b, alpha);
        shopButton.getButton().setColor(shopButton.getButton().getColor().r, shopButton.getButton().getColor().g, shopButton.getButton().getColor().b, alpha);
        scoreFont.setColor(scoreFont.getColor().r, scoreFont.getColor().g, scoreFont.getColor().b, alpha);
        openable = false;
    } else {
        alpha += (2.5f * delta);
    }
}

public void changeScreen(float delta) {
    playButton.getButton().setColor(playButton.getButton().getColor().r, playButton.getButton().getColor().g, playButton.getButton().getColor().b, alpha);
    shopButton.getButton().setColor(shopButton.getButton().getColor().r, shopButton.getButton().getColor().g, shopButton.getButton().getColor().b, alpha);
    scoreFont.setColor(scoreFont.getColor().r, scoreFont.getColor().g, scoreFont.getColor().b, alpha);

    if (alpha - (2.5f * delta) <= 0 && option == 1) {
        game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game, assetsClass, preferencesHelper));
        dispose();
    } else if (alpha - (2.f * delta) <= 0 && option == 2) {
        game.setScreen(new InGameShop(game, assetsClass, preferencesHelper));
        dispose();
    } else {
        alpha -= (2.5f * delta);
    }
}
```

which is called on render... There are a few more sprite's in render, but they are handled the same way! So the change screen is working fine, but open screen can be laggy!

Comment: create them invisible first then fade them in?

Comment: those sprite's alpha = 0.0f when the screen is created, so they are invisible, but when the screen is created, in that moment it is all laggish, so it barely shows any fade in effect, if any, or sometimes it is nice and smooth.

Comment: post some code, it may be a race-condition of some kind.

Comment: added code above, and notice, when setScreen is called, it sets openable to true and alpha to 0.0f, and if openable is true it runs openScreen method, same logic aplies to closable.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, however as you say yourself the game is lagging when the app is loading. This means there are fewer frames to show the fade in effect because the deltaTime goes up.

What you can do to counter this is to have a max deltaTime in which you do the fading like:

```
if (alpha + (2.5f * delta) >= 1) {
        ...
    } else if (delta < someSmallDelta) {
        alpha += (2.5f * delta);
    }
```

Btw, to releave you of the nitty gritty of these animations you might want to look into [Universal Tween Engine](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/universal-tween-engine/) or [scene2d actions](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#actions)

Comment: Tried a few things with setting max, but doesn't work, because my spike is to big... When I load to my main menu, the first 5 x delta's are about 0.07 and then it drops back to 0.017... Although I don't get it why not only the first delta is 0.07 but there are 5... Aren't those delta time's the time that it took the render to render everything? Well every object is created in the constructor!

Comment: I changed the code now so that it checks if alpha <= 0 and alpha >= 1 then alpha == 0 and alpha == 1, so that they are almost invisible, and delta <= 0.04, which I hope will work for all devices, so now it works alot, alot smother, although sometimes I can still see the sprites, because they don't totally vanish, any optimization ideas?